# Bar chart with ticks based on multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

How can I make a bar chart in matplotlib (or pandas) from the bins in my dataframe?

I want something like this, below, where the x-axis labels come from the `low`, `high` in my dataframe (so first tick would read `[-1.089, 0)` and the y value is the `percent` column in my dataframe.

[image]

Here is an example dataset. The dataset is already in this format (I don't have an uncut version).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "low": [-1.089, 0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8],
        "high": [0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 10.089],
        "percent": [0.509, 0.11, 0.074, 0.038, 0.069, 0.202],
    }
)
display(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column using the the low, high cols.

Covert the int values in the low and high columns to str type and set the new str in the `[<low>, <high>)` notation that you want.

From there, you can create a bar plot dirrectly from `df` using `df.plot.bar()`, assigning the newly created column as x and percent as y.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you. I used `df['label'] = "[" + df['low'].map(str) + ", " + df['high'].map(str) + ")"` to concatenate the two columns, worked perfectly

Comment: Perfect! Here's another for fun: `df["label"] = df.apply(lambda x: "[" + x["low"].astype(str) + "," + x["high"].astype(str) + ")", axis = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Recreate the bins using [`IntervalArray.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays.html):

```
df['label'] = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(df.low, df.high)
#      low    high  percent          label
# 0 -1.089   0.000    0.509  (-1.089, 0.0]
# 1  0.000   0.300    0.110     (0.0, 0.3]
# 2  0.300   0.500    0.074     (0.3, 0.5]
# 3  0.500   0.600    0.038     (0.5, 0.6]
# 4  0.600   0.800    0.069     (0.6, 0.8]
# 5  0.800  10.089    0.202  (0.8, 10.089]
```

Then plot with `x` as these bins:

```
df.plot.bar(x='label', y='percent')
```

[image]

Comment: that is a nice and clean solution, thank you